# Displaying a wait cursor while we're waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, gui

I come from VB6 where everything is single threaded, so I've never written a lick of multi-threaded code before. I just added a wait cursor to one of our GUI's by stumbling through the docs, but I'm unsure I've done it the best way. Did I?

`Control` is a Winform view and the code below is located in the presenter class. Full file can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/90d030e280ee64349f365253d7797f2406de72d0/RetailCoder.VBE/UI/ToDoItems/ToDoExplorerDockablePresenter.cs#L62-L102).

```
    private void RefreshToDoList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            var getItems = new Task<IOrderedEnumerable<ToDoItem>>(() => GetItems());
            getItems.Start();

            Control.TodoItems = getItems.Result;
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }

private IOrderedEnumerable<ToDoItem> GetItems()
{
    var items = new ConcurrentBag<ToDoItem>();
    var projects = VBE.VBProjects.Cast<VBProject>();
    Parallel.ForEach(projects,
        project =>
        {
            var modules = _parser.Parse(project);
            foreach (var module in modules)
            {
                var markers = module.Comments.AsParallel().SelectMany(GetToDoMarkers);
                foreach (var marker in markers)
                {
                    items.Add(marker);
                }
            }
        });

    var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(item => item.ProjectName)
                            .ThenBy(item => item.ModuleName)
                            .ThenByDescending(item => item.Priority)
                            .ThenBy(item => item.LineNumber);

    return sortedItems;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew unless you specifically want to put your work on a new thread, which Parallel.ForEach already does. Also the order by is not executed in your async block by the task, it is executed as it is assigned. This is probably not what you want so you should do a .ToArray at the end of the order by sequence.

```
private async Task<IOrderedEnumerable<ToDoItem>> GetItems()
{
    await Task.Yield(); //returns the Task here so the UI can process
    var items = new ConcurrentBag<ToDoItem>();
    var projects = VBE.VBProjects.Cast<VBProject>();
    Parallel.ForEach(projects, project =>
    {
        var modules = _parser.Parse(project);
        foreach (var module in modules)
        {
            var markers = module.Comments.AsParallel().SelectMany(GetToDoMarkers);
            foreach (var marker in markers)
            {
                items.Add(marker);
            }
        }
    });

    var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(item => item.ProjectName)
                        .ThenBy(item => item.ModuleName)
                        .ThenByDescending(item => item.Priority)
                        .ThenBy(item => item.LineNumber).ToArray();

    return sortedItems;
}
```

Then in your Refresh:

```
private async void RefreshToDoList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Control.ToDoItems = await GetItems();
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RubberDuck I think you can probably do without the try/finally at this point, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I don't think so @moarboilerplate. You need to be 100% certain the cursor gets set back.

Comment: @RubberDuck is this to handle uncaught exceptions?

Comment: Yes @moarboilerplate. It might not be necessary, but if an untrapped exception does occur, I *know* the cursor.

Comment: @RubberDuck Got it. Might want to have a log or something like that for ease in debugging.

Comment: The exception would still be thrown and the stack trace preserved @moarboilerplate. Just higher up the call stack.

Comment: If you make an `IDisposable` helper object to change cursors, you can do it in a using statement.  It will work the same as a try/finally, but it will look a little cleaner.  OTOH, it is perhaps a little abusive of `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition was correct, you're not doing asynchronicity the right way.

Take a look at this bit of code:

```
var getItems = new Task<IOrderedEnumerable<ToDoItem>>(() => GetItems());
getItems.Start();
Control.TodoItems = getItems.Result;
```

You're creating a new task, starting it and then you synchronously block the current thread by calling `.Result`. A new thread isn't created just by creating a `Task` object, that's what async/await is for.

Instead, change your method as such (omitting cursor and try/catch for clarity):

```
private async void RefreshToDoList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control.TodoItems = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetItems());
}

private IOrderedEnumerable<ToDoItem> GetItems()
{
    // Everything else is the same here
}
```

This incorporates a few changes. First of all: I've made the event handler `async void`. This is the only situation where it is advised to do this, simply because there's no alternative: event handlers have the requirement to have a `void` return type whereas asynchronous methods work with `Task`.

In essence this means that you won't be able to `await` the event handler so if the caller finishes while the event's effects are still running, your program will exit without a regard of this still running code.

Another change is that I used `Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate);`. [You can choose between this and `Task.Run(delegate)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160720084501/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) but both are more fluent than creating a new `Task` object and then starting it.

You should always avoid calling [`.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-6.0) since it synchronously blocks the thread to wait for the result (which is the opposite of what you typically want in an asynchronous environment).

As shown in the docs:

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the `Wait` method.

The only reason I'm creating a new task from the caller is because `GetItems()` doesn't return one. Typically you want asynchronicity throughout the entire hierarchy but I didn't see where it would've been used in `GetItems()`.
However, if you ever call an asynchronous method then it returns `Task` or `Task<T>` and you can simply use `await MyMethodAsync()`.

Comment: I've looked at this a bit, and I don't believe it behaves the same. I actually need the `.Result` to synchronously block so the cursor doesn't immediately flip back from waiting to normal. The async code is really just to allow the GUI to update the cursor. Still, you've given me a lot of good information and I thank you for that.

Comment: Using `Task.Factory.StartNew` is inadvisable: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @DanielMann: very interesting read, thanks! I could have sworn I saw `Task.Factory.StartNew` recommended typically but I'll take Stephen Cleary's word on everything async related.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to rethink your approach here. You're using PLINQ, which is used to speed up your LINQ by distributing the processing across multiple cores. To solve your cursor issue, all you really want is just a very simple implementation using the async and await keywords without messing around with tasks and PLINQ. You can go there when you want to speed up your actual query.

Jeroen Vannevel's solution is for the most part correct; execution will pause until the task being awaited is complete and will not immediately switch the cursor.

I would only make one small change to the implementation he provided--I would not invoke the task, just call `var items = await GetItems();` and change the signature to this:

```
private async Task<IOrderedEnumerable<ToDoItem>> GetItems()
```

That should get you what you need; you don't even need a try/finally, just put your logic to revert the cursor right after the call to GetItems.

Comment: Thanks. The PLinq was actually written by my co-dev to address a performance issue. I'll try your & Jeroen's suggestions out soon.