# Notifying the UI that Issues Were Found

Tags: c#, event-handling, gui, async-await, rubberduck

Our [Rubberduck VBA IDE Add In](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck) does some static code analysis, and then reports all of the found issues back in a gridview. This analysis can take a long time for larger projects and the UI appeared to be frozen until all of the analysis was complete. I've corrected that issue by updating the number of issues found as they're found and now I'm wondering if there is anything else in this code I can improve prior to merging the branch in.

I'm just learning about `async` code, so I'm particularly interested in how we've done that. Some of it feels wrong and dirty, but I don't know well enough to be entirely sure. I did my best to apply what I learned in a [recent review of some other code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82160/displaying-a-wait-cursor-while-were-waiting).

For reference, this is what the UI looks like.

[image: Code Inspection Results]

I extracted the Inspection logic into it's own class and interface to inject into the presenter along with the view. The idea is to have the presenter listen for issues being found by the inspector and update the GUI asynchronously, while the inspector in turn asynchronously searchers for issues in the VBProject.

Headers link to this particular version of the files on GitHub and I can add any code not here that you find relevant upon request.

[**IInspector:**](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/1e096f92aa7956162d36ba1db2079fc6f80114f3/RetailCoder.VBE/Inspections/IInspector.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rubberduck.Inspections
{
    public interface IInspector
    {
        Task<IList<ICodeInspectionResult>> FindIssues(VBProject project);
        event EventHandler<InspectorIssuesFoundEventArg> IssuesFound;
    }

    public class InspectorIssuesFoundEventArg : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly int _count;
        public int Count { get { return _count; } }

        public InspectorIssuesFoundEventArg(int count)
        {
            _count = count;
        }
    }
}
```

[**Inspector:**](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/1e096f92aa7956162d36ba1db2079fc6f80114f3/RetailCoder.VBE/Inspections/Inspector.cs)

```
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using Rubberduck.VBA;
using Rubberduck.VBA.Nodes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rubberduck.Inspections
{
    public class Inspector : IInspector
    {
        private readonly IRubberduckParser _parser;
        private readonly IList<IInspection> _inspections;

        public Inspector(IRubberduckParser parser, IEnumerable<IInspection> inspections)
        {
            _parser = parser;
            _inspections = inspections.ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IList<ICodeInspectionResult>> FindIssues(VBProject project)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            var code = new VBProjectParseResult(_parser.Parse(project));
            var results = new ConcurrentBag<ICodeInspectionResult>();

            var inspections = _inspections.Where(inspection => inspection.Severity != CodeInspectionSeverity.DoNotShow)
                .Select(inspection =>
                    new Task(() =>
                    {
                        var result = inspection.GetInspectionResults(code);
                        var count = result.Count();
                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            RaiseIssuesFound(count);

                            foreach (var inspectionResult in result)
                            {
                                results.Add(inspectionResult);
                            }
                        }
                    })).ToArray();

            foreach (var inspection in inspections)
            {
                inspection.Start();
            }

            Task.WaitAll(inspections);

            return results.ToList();
        }

        public event EventHandler<InspectorIssuesFoundEventArg> IssuesFound;
        private void RaiseIssuesFound(int count)
        {
            var handler = IssuesFound;
            if (handler == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var args = new InspectorIssuesFoundEventArg(count);
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

[**CodeInspectionDockablePresenter:**](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/1e096f92aa7956162d36ba1db2079fc6f80114f3/RetailCoder.VBE/UI/CodeInspections/CodeInspectionsDockablePresenter.cs)

```
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using Rubberduck.Extensions;
using Rubberduck.Inspections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rubberduck.UI.CodeInspections
{
    public class CodeInspectionsDockablePresenter : DockablePresenterBase
    {
        private CodeInspectionsWindow Control { get { return UserControl as CodeInspectionsWindow; } }

        private IList<ICodeInspectionResult> _results;
        private IInspector _inspector;

        public CodeInspectionsDockablePresenter(IInspector inspector, VBE vbe, AddIn addin, CodeInspectionsWindow window)
            :base(vbe, addin, window)
        {
            _inspector = inspector;

            _inspector.IssuesFound += OnIssuesFound;

            Control.RefreshCodeInspections += OnRefreshCodeInspections;
            Control.NavigateCodeIssue += OnNavigateCodeIssue;
            Control.QuickFix += OnQuickFix;
        }

        private void OnIssuesFound(object sender, InspectorIssuesFoundEventArg e)
        {
            var newCount = Control.IssueCount + e.Count;
            Control.IssueCount = newCount;
            Control.IssueCountText = string.Format("{0} issue" + (newCount > 1 ? "s" : string.Empty), newCount);
        }

        private void OnQuickFix(object sender, QuickFixEventArgs e)
        {
            e.QuickFix(VBE);
            OnRefreshCodeInspections(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public override void Show()
        {
            base.Show();

            if (VBE.ActiveVBProject != null)
            {
                OnRefreshCodeInspections(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        private void OnNavigateCodeIssue(object sender, NavigateCodeEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var location = VBE.FindInstruction(e.QualifiedName, e.Selection);
                location.CodeModule.CodePane.SetSelection(e.Selection);

                var codePane = location.CodeModule.CodePane;
                var selection = location.Selection;
                codePane.SetSelection(selection);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, exception.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void OnRefreshCodeInspections(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        private async void Refresh()
        {
            Control.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            try
            {
                Control.IssueCount = 0;
                Control.IssueCountText = "0 issues";
                Control.InspectionResults.Clear();

                _results = await this._inspector.FindIssues(VBE.ActiveVBProject);
                Control.SetContent(_results.Select(item => new CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem(item)).OrderBy(item => item.Component).ThenBy(item => item.Line));
            }
            finally
            {
                Control.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You are still using the UI thread to do the project parsing `_parser.Parse(project)`, because `Task.Yield` will return the execution back to UI thread. If this call may take significant time, I would suggest to replace it with `Task.Run`.
2. It looks like you should get exceptions in `OnIssuesFound`, as you're updating the UI from non-UI thread. See the fix below.
3. What you do with `IssuesFound` event is actually reporting progress. .NET has a built-in support for asynchronous progress reporting via `IProgress<T>` and `Progress<T>`, which properly handles the synchronization with UI thread. See description of how to use them here: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)
4. Instead of `new Task()` and then `task.Start` you can just use the `Task.Run` method to create and run the task.
5. Don't use `Task.WaitAll` as it blocks the thread until all tasks complete. Use `await Task.WhenAll()` instead.

As a result, my take on `FindIssues` refactoring look like this:

```
public async Task<IList<ICodeInspectionResult>> FindIssuesAsync(VBProject project, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    var code = await Task.Run(() => new VBProjectParseResult(_parser.Parse(project))).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var inspections = _inspections.Where(inspection => inspection.Severity != CodeInspectionSeverity.DoNotShow)
                .Select(inspection =>
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        var result = inspection.GetInspectionResults(code).ToArray();
                        var count = result.Count();
                        if (progress != null && count > 0)
                            progress.Report(count);

                        return result;
                    }));

    ICodeInspectionResult[][] results = await Task.WhenAll(inspections);

    return results.SelectMany(enumerable => enumerable).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting exceptions of any kind though. The code seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Task.Run spins up a new thread, I wouldn't do that unless I know that the work is CPU bound. Task.Yield will return the call to the calling thread and place the work onto another thread in the threadpool or spin it up, it will be async wrt to the UI. I agree with await Task.WhenAll

Comment: @JasonLind Awaiting `Task.Yield` will put the rest of the work on the `SynchronizationContext` corresponding to the UI thread, i.e. rest of the method will run on UI thread. I don't think it is the intention.
`Task.Run` does not necessarily spin up a thread, it [schedules the execution on the `ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RubberDuck I'm just looking at your code, didn't run it. You're raising `IssuesFound` event from the thread pool (not UI thread), and directly update the UI from the event handler. Anyway, `IProgress<T>` is the better way to report progress to the UI thread.

Comment: Yeah... Idk. I do agree that `IProgress<T>` is called for here though. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use Task.Start as that kicks off a new thread (unless you know the work is CPU bound), I'd use async/await in the following manor:

```
 var inspections = _inspections.Where(inspection => inspection.Severity != CodeInspectionSeverity.DoNotShow)
            .Select(inspection =>ProcessInspection(inspection, progress)).ToArray();
private async Task<ICodeInspectionResult[]> ProcessInspection(IInspection inspection, IProgress<int> progress)
{
   await Task.Yield();
   var result = inspection.GetInspectionResults(code).ToArray();
   var count = result.Count();
   if (progress != null && count > 0)
       progress.Report(count);

   return result;

}
```

A thread may or may not be spun up based on the runtime threadpool requirements, you shouldn't spin up threads directly unless you know the work is CPU bound.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about this snippet

> ```
> var inspections = _inspections.Where(inspection => inspection.Severity != CodeInspectionSeverity.DoNotShow)
>     .Select(inspection =>
>         new Task(() =>
>         {
>             var result = inspection.GetInspectionResults(code);
>             var count = result.Count();
>             if (count > 0)
>             {
>                 RaiseIssuesFound(count);
>
>                 foreach (var inspectionResult in result)
>                 {
>                     results.Add(inspectionResult);
>                 }
>             }
>         })).ToArray();
> ```

Calling `inspection.GetInspectionResults()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` so if you are calling `Count()` on the result, this call is iterating over the `IEnumerable` and later you are iterating again if `count > 0`.

A better approach is to use `Any()` and rearange the code to call `RaiseIssuesFound()` after iterating over the `IEnumerable`.

Because an `IEnumerable` indicates a kind of "collection" one should name the variable holding this by using the pluralform.

```
var inspections = _inspections.Where(inspection => inspection.Severity != CodeInspectionSeverity.DoNotShow)
    .Select(inspection =>
        new Task(() =>
        {
            var inspectionResults = inspection.GetInspectionResults(code);
            if (inspectionResults.Any())
            {
                var count = 0;
                foreach (var inspectionResult in inspectionResults)
                {
                    results.Add(inspectionResult);
                    count++;
                }
                RaiseIssuesFound(count);
            }
        })).ToArray();
```